# Sales products list layered

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I need to create a page that automatically shows a list of all products with catalog rules applied. This page should also include layered navigation.

**Which is te best way to achieve it?**

I tried creating a page and link it to a block:

> {{block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Sales"
>   template="Vendor_ModuleName::sales.phtml"}}

And appended layered navigation in Layout Update XML area, linking Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation overriding Magento Layered navigation.

Then, in my module I created the sales.phtml page inside /view/frontend/templates with the view on it and the block/Sales.php, with a custom product collection.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if(count($params)){
            // Make sure array key is attribute code
            foreach($params as $key => $value) {
                if ($key != "page_id") {
                    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($key,array('eq' => intval($value)));
                }
            }
        }
        $this->_productCollection->getSize();
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

The thing is that I'm able to show products correctly but when I filter I'm facing several problems:

- It appends a search_tmp_xxx table that makes no result returned
- It makes that layered navigation appends the attribute and value to url when filter applied but not refreshing data until you manually refresh the page
- The attribute count in layered navigation does not count items correctly